# What is the difference between arrow functions and normal function when writing Unit Test cases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am creating a react component and in this component I am using arrow functions for class methods and lifecycle hooks. I am writing unit test cases for the same file. But the issue is,
When I write lifecycle hook in old javascript way like

```
componentDidMount(){
  ...Here
}
```

and running the test coverage then this lifecycle method is getting covered automatically. But when I write it like

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  ...Here    
}
```

and running the code coverage it is not getting covered in Unit test and showing "Statement is not covered".

So my question is that what is the difference between these two ways when writing Unit test cases?

Comment: Might be helpful https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10810

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference, the first one creates a method and the 2nd one created a property and not a method, so it does not exist in the prototype.

You can use it by binding it in the constructor but arrow functions in lifecycle events are going to hurt performance.